# Consuming Web Service from javascript in .net page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

How to do it? I am completely new to this and wish to start learning it. I am going to have a tree structure, most probably a html/Javascript tree which will need to be saved into the database through Web Services.

What is the most efficient way to do this with ASP .net web services + asp.net 3.5?

UPDATED:
thanks for all the answers, I am still missing some pieces to this scenario, namely:
1) when the node is to be added to the tree, a user will get a pop-up, where some info will be entered, saved in the database, and a integer code returned from the database. Upon it's return, I need do some logic, and insert a node(or several) into the node selected. And so on, so forth. SO from what i understand, this logic (the meat of the code) will have to be performed on the client, in my Javascript code.
2) What would trigger the tree "refresh" after the pop-up is closed? 
3) Where is .net with this picture at all? From what I gather, no server-side coding is performed here at all (aside from Web Services). 
Is that the general direction these days, step away from server-side coding with .net controls and use a Javascript lib of choice + web services?

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using ASP.net Ajax calls. On the server-side you create a webservice (WCF or asmx) having the attribute ScriptService:

```
namespace MyCompany.Project.Services
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class MyWebServiceClass : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string GreetFromServer(string name)
        {
            return "Hello, " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

On the page, you add a ScriptManager referencing your webservice.

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="scriptManager" runat="server">
   <Services>
      <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Services/MyWebServiceClass"/>
   </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Then on the client side (JavaScript):

```
function invokeService(){
   MyCompany.Project.Services.MyWebServiceClass.GreetFromServer("Juri", onSuccess, onFailure);
}

function onSuccess(result){
  //check if result different null etc..It will be in JSON format, so deserialize
  //use result
}

function onFailure(){
   //handle errors
}
```

That should just be a hint on how to create a service and access it from within JavaScript. I mostly wrote it out of my head now, without checking it.
A hint: use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)! It's really great for verifying the data that is sent back and forth between your JavaScript client code and the webservice on the server-side.

I've [just written a blog post](http://blog.js-development.com/2009/11/aspnet-ajax-consuming-webservice-from.html) with a downloadable example that describes the communication of client-server using asmx as well as WCF webservices.

Comment: I just added a link to a blog post I've written related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Encosia.com has everything you need:

[Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

Comment: thanks, I however am still unclear on this part: 
on form submit, someone is going to have to write code on the client to collect that data and send it via Ajax to a server method.

From what i heard, Jquery doesn't play well with Asp.net. Is it old news? How am i going to trigger the page to refresh (call the server method via Ajax) with Jquery? none of these links tell me how to do that.

Comment: Jquery will play very well with asp.net http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use jquery on the client side in your html / Javascript tree. Here is a tutorial to get you started on using jquery with asp.net

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

Comment: yes, but can I consume asp.net web services from within Jquery? I only found one resource on how to do it:
http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2009/07/11/133402.aspx 
and it looks like a pain. Any experiences with that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look

[Consuming a Web Service using ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.webreference.com/programming/asp/Ajax_WebService/)